# Use PHP on my computer offline

Tags: php

I am learning PHP.The problem is that I don't have a frequent internet access.Every time to practice PHP i have to go online. Is there a way to practice PHP+HTML on my computer without internet connection.
Thanks

Comment: Just install something like [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/).

Comment: Just install something like wampserver or mamp.²

Comment: Just install something like wampserver or mamp.³

Comment: Just install something like wampserver or mamp.⁴

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install xampp or wamp in your computer and install one of then.

https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html

Never use xampp in client server. xampp only for developers